# php and table formatting

Tags: php, joomla

hi everyone i have the following php that i would like to set each echo command in its own table row, but i'm having issues....somewhere....

```
<?php
$db=JFactory::getDBO();
$q = "select * from #__jbjobs_employer where user_id=".$job->employer_id;
$db->setQuery($q);
$employer_record = $db->loadObject();
echo ($employer_record->show_addr == 'y')? "Address: ".$employer_record->street_addr.', '.$employer_record->city.', '.$employer_record->state : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED').'<br>';
echo ($employer_record->show_phone == 'y')? "Phone: ".$employer_record->primary_phone : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED').'<br>';  
echo ($employer_record->show_fax == 'y')? "Fax: ".$employer_record->fax_number : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED').'<br>';  
$u = JFactory::getUser($job->employer_id);
echo ($employer_record->show_email == 'y')? "Email:".$u->email : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED');                                              
?>
```

i attempted doing it with the snippet below, but given that i know nothing about php, everything shows in one line with no table in sight

```
<?php
$db=JFactory::getDBO();
$q = "select * from #__jbjobs_employer where user_id=".$job->employer_id;
$db->setQuery($q);
$employer_record = $db->loadObject();                                           
            '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
               <td>';echo ($employer_record->show_addr == 'y')? "".$employer_record->street_addr : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED').'</tr>
              <tr>
                <td>';
echo ($employer_record->show_location == 'y')? "".$employer_record->city.', '.$employer_record->state : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED').'</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>';
echo ($employer_record->show_phone == 'y')? "".$employer_record->primary_phone : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED').'</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>';  
echo ($employer_record->show_fax == 'y')? "".$employer_record->fax_number : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED').'</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>';  
$u = JFactory::getUser($job->employer_id);
echo ($employer_record->show_email == 'y')? "".$u->email : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED');'</td>
          </td>
              </tr>
          </table>'
?>
```

can someone lend a hand please? thanks!!!!

Comment: you missed an `echo` in your 6th line?

Comment: my info shows, but it's all in one line with no table.

Comment: There is also a missing closing </td> at line 8. sometimes tables can misbehave when tags mismatch

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should write your query like so which uses up to date Joomla coding standards

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('*'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__jbjobs_employer'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('user_id') . ' = '. $db->quote($job->employer_id);
$db->setQuery($query);
$employer_record = $db->loadObject();
```

Then to display it, you need to use `echo` before your table like so:

```
echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

Also, on a side note, you need to close your opening `td` on the first set of results, so change this:

```
JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED').'</tr>
```

to this:

```
JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED').'</td>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 ^^^^---you forgot this
```

Comment: thanks everyone. i added the missing echo, the missing </td> and removed an extra </td> from the third line from the bottom.
still no formatting though. results are in one single line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you missed an `echo` in your 6th line,

```
<?php
$db=JFactory::getDBO();
$q = "select * from #__jbjobs_employer where user_id=".$job->employer_id;
$db->setQuery($q);
$employer_record = $db->loadObject();                                           
echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
               <td>';echo ($employer_record->show_addr == 'y')? "".$employer_record->street_addr : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED').'</td>
              </tr>
              <tr><td>';
echo ($employer_record->show_location == 'y')? "".$employer_record->city.', '.$employer_record->state : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED').'</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>';
echo ($employer_record->show_phone == 'y')? "".$employer_record->primary_phone : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED').'</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>';  
echo ($employer_record->show_fax == 'y')? "".$employer_record->fax_number : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED').'</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>';  
$u = JFactory::getUser($job->employer_id);
echo ($employer_record->show_email == 'y')? "".$u->email : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED');'</td>
          </tr>
          </table>'
?>
```

Comment: thanks everyone. i added the missing echo, the missing </td> and removed an extra </td> from the third line from the bottom. still no formatting though. results are in one single line.

Comment: @user2800989 I have edited the code, try copying and pasting this.

Answer (score 0):

so here's what I did and it worked:

```
<?php
echo "<table width='100%' border='0'>";
$db=JFactory::getDBO();
$q = "select * from #__jbjobs_employer where user_id=".$job->employer_id;
$db->setQuery($q);
$employer_record = $db->loadObject();
echo "<tr><td>";
echo ($employer_record->show_addr == 'y')? "".$employer_record->street_addr : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED');
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo ($employer_record->show_location == 'y')? "".$employer_record->city.', '.$employer_record->state : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED');
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo ($employer_record->show_phone == 'y')? "".$employer_record->primary_phone : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED');
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo ($employer_record->show_fax == 'y')? "".$employer_record->fax_number : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED');
$u = JFactory::getUser($job->employer_id);
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo ($employer_record->show_email == 'y')? "".$u->email : JText::_('JBJOBS_NOT_DISPLAYED');
echo "</table>";
?>
```